# In my Xcode's SpriteKit game project. I tagged some Sprite Atlas to On Demand Resources' Tags but not loading in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, testflight, on-demand-resources

My game's new version used On Demand Resources with Sprite Atlas. Everything work fine in Simulator until I submitted a version to AppStoreConnect and install through TestFlight. All Sprite Atlas' assets only show "X" inside my game. Is it TestFlight's bug? Can I still submit for Review and will it working fine in App Store version?

I created a testing project to reproduce this issue. If I run the project in the Simulator, nothing bad happens, but when I create an archive, then upload it to "AppStoreConnect" and finally install it through TestFlight, it doesn't work.

https://github.com/piplay/TestODRWithSpriteAtlas